# Assistance with a java program that counts up to a number, in binary

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, binary

I've recently taken up a computer organization course in where we learn binary hex etc, I took it upon myself to attempt to create a program that will count from 0 up to an input number, however the counting is done in binary. I've run into some trouble and confused myself beyond belief, some clarification and assistance would be greatly appreciated. Specifically speaking, how can I efficiently and effectively replace the values of a string containing the previous binary number, with 0's and 1's using some sort of for-loop. I'm aware that there is some method for directly converting a string to binary, however; I wanted to do this more complicated method for practice.

```
package counting;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class counting 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Hello, this is a number counter, please enter the integer you would like to count to");
    int number = input.nextInt();
    String start = "0000000000";
    // 000~etc is used as the start simply because i'm not sure how to calculate how many digit places
    //the number input by the user will have

    StringBuilder cont = new StringBuilder(start);

    System.out.println(start);

    /*What i intend to do is have the binary loop counter continue until it reaches
     * the number input by the user, afterwards, working in a right to left manner, start counting from
     * 0 up to the number given by the user, starting with 0. then using another loop, still using
     * the right to left manner, if there is a 0, it should be replaced with a 1, and if there is a
     * 1, it should be replaced with a 0, and the character before it should be replaced with a 1, if there
     * is no room, continue to the left until there is a space available for a 1 and then reset all values
     * after the 1 back to zero, and resume counting. the way i see it is requires a for loop to be used
     * as the current position of a cursor used to determine what changes must be made
     */

    for(int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        int l = start.length();
        for(int n = 0; n <= number; n++)
        {

            for(int w = 1; w <= l; w++) 
            {

                if (cont.charAt(l-w) == '0')
                {
                    cont.setCharAt((cont.length()-w), '1');

                    System.out.println(cont);
                }

                else if (cont.charAt(l-w) == '1')
                {
                    cont.setCharAt((cont.length()-w), '0');
                    cont.setCharAt((cont.length()-(w+1)), '1');

                    System.out.println(cont);
                }

            }
        }
        System.out.println(cont);
        }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little loop that will do what you are looking for. You just have to remember powers of 2 to count in binary.

```
public static char flip(char c){
    if(c == '0')
        return '1';
    else 
        return '0';
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String start = "0000000000";

    StringBuilder cont = new StringBuilder(start);

    int number = (int)Math.pow(2,10);

    for(int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        if(i != 0){

            int val = (int)Math.floor(i/2);

            for(int j = 0; j <= val; j++){
                // Flip any bit that when modded by 2^j == 0
                if(i % Math.pow(2,j) == 0){

                    cont.setCharAt((cont.length() - (j + 1)), flip(cont.charAt(cont.length() - (j + 1))));
                }
            }
        }   

        System.out.println(cont);

    }   
}
```